# How to convert array of numbers to timestamp in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, type-conversion

I have date value stored in a format like this:

```
"timestamp": [
 2020,
 2,
 14,
 15,
 45,
 47,
 8000000
]
```

I have no idea what this format is. I haven't found any solution on how to convert this array of numbers into a MySQL timestamp via MySQL tools. Could anybody give me a clue about it?

Comment: *I have date value stored in a format like this* WHERE it is stored in this format? In a field of JSON datatype? And what is the meaning of the last component ('8000000')?

Comment: Yeah, the "timestamp" field is a field of JSON that stored as a 'mediumtext' column. The last component seems to be a fraction of seconds.

Comment: Create a fiddle with some example data (3-4 records is enough). *The last component seems to be a fraction of seconds.* Max. timestamp accuracy in MySQL is 6 digits after decimal point (1 mks), whereas you use 8 digits...

Comment: [2020, 2, 18, 16, 42, 48, 939000000]; [2020, 2, 19, 15, 7, 38, 127000000]; [2020, 2, 18, 12, 10, 13, 851000000]; [2020, 2, 19, 15, 27, 26, 69000000]. Here are some values of that field. Sorry for bad formatting of this comment...

Comment: I have asked for a fiddle. If you cannot then edit your question and add `CREATE TABLE` script and `INSERT INTO` script with 3-4 records values. Excess fields and indices may be skipped. And specify the meaning of the value of the last parameter and the way it is interpreted.